# Getting HiRes Tiles via WMTS results in Incorrect size of download block?

Tags: gdal, tiles, wmts

To use maps in prints we'd like to use HiRes Tiles offered by a server ([basemap.at](https://www.basemap.at)) providing WMTS tiles sized 512x512.

The example on https://www.gdal.org/frmt_wmts.html works well for standard tiles sized 256x256 but fails for the HiRes (512x512) resolution resulting in the following error:

```
ERROR 1: GDALWMS: Incorrect size 512 x 512 of downloaded block, expected 256 x 256, max 256 x 256.
ERROR 1: GDALWMS: ReadBlockFromFile (https://maps1.wien.gv.at/basemap/bmaphidpi/normal/google3857/19/182218/285835.jpeg) failed.
ERROR 1: GDAL_WMS>, band 1: IReadBlock failed at X offset 0, Y offset 0
ERROR 1: GetBlockRef failed at X block offset 0, Y block offset 0
```

Are we missing any (undocumented) tags in the WMTS XML?

---

wmts.xml:

```
<GDAL_WMTS>
<GetCapabilitiesUrl>https://www.basemap.at/wmts/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml</GetCapabilitiesUrl>
  <Layer>bmaphidpi</Layer>
  <Style>normal</Style>
  <TileMatrixSet>google3857</TileMatrixSet>
  <ZoomLevel>19</ZoomLevel>
  <Format>image/jpeg</Format>
  <DataWindow>
    <UpperLeftX>1810893.1</UpperLeftX>
    <UpperLeftY>6109237.0</UpperLeftY>
    <LowerRightX>1811214.4</LowerRightX>
    <LowerRightY>6109038.2</LowerRightY>
  </DataWindow>
  <BandsCount>4</BandsCount>
  <Cache />
  <UnsafeSSL>true</UnsafeSSL>
  <ZeroBlockHttpCodes>204,404</ZeroBlockHttpCodes>  <ZeroBlockOnServerException>true</ZeroBlockOnServerException>
</GDAL_WMTS>
```

Python script:

```
from osgeo import gdal
ds = gdal.Open('wmts.xml')
gdal.GetDriverByName('JPEG').CreateCopy('map_z19.jpg', ds)
```

GDAL version 2.2.2, Python 3.6

Comment: I believe the issue is in the server TileMatrixSet, it says the tiles are 256x256.